# Single Activity intent.action.VIEW with Crashlytics-Beta causing two instances of App running at same time

Tags: android, android-manifest, crashlytics-beta

i have run into very strange behavior of crashlytics beta when tester claims he is able to run two instances of app at the same time.

[image]

Log is telling me that its completely same packageName so we cant distinguish from which that log came.

I did some research and beta is propably running it inside their app with something like this:

```
Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.ofapp");
startActivity(i);
```

with combination of `action.View` in manifest its causing to run two instances of the app

```
<activity android:name="com.kebab.KebabApp">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So i would say its ok. Just lets get rid of the action.View.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

After that its start screaming at me:

> App is not indexable by Google Search; consider adding at least one
>   Activity with an ACTION-VIEW intent-filler. See issue explanation for
>   more details.

So i have to put ignoring GoogleAppIndexingWarning into lint because i am using google single app standard combining with crashlytics beta ?

Comment: The warning you get `App is not indexable by Google Search` can be ignored, it has nothing to do with your issue. Please provide your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my manifest @HB

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="package">

    <!-- permissions -->

    <application
        android:name="package"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="${appIcon}"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="${roundIcon}"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="package.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```